# Interactive rescheduling Gantt Chart in Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle-apex

Is it possible to have an interactive gantt chart in oracle that allows you to drag and drop(or slide) bars ( tasks ) to reschedule them?

Answer (score 0):

Since to render Gantt, Apex uses AnyChart, I think its possible since any chart hosts a demo here: http://playground.anychart.com/gallery/7.12.0/Gantt_Live_Editing/Editing_Events
I'll update after I try it out.